# What's the fastest way to display the block height with a shell script?

Tags: block-explorer, block-height

What's the fastest way to display the current Monero block height with a shell script? Doesn't matter which scripting language. The idea is to call this script or block from other scripts, so it should just return the value.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what you're doing? Do you have the daemon at your disposal, for instance, or are you limited to online APIs?

Comment: Sure. I have an Applescript dialog, wherein I enter a specific block number, to then show the transactions for it in Safari. The default value in the dialog is the current block height, which is looked up by this shell script. I don’t have a local daemon on this particular computer, so I think I need to go out to the block explorer. I haven’t thought about where it would be possible to interrogate a remote daemon to retrieve the same info. Is it possible?

Comment: yep, it's possible. See my answer below :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I propose the following with simple bash scripting using `curl` and `jq`.

---

**First**, install jq (to parse json)

- macOS: `brew install jq`
- Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install jq`
- Others at https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/

---

**Then**, write a simple bash script

Using the moneroclub public node:

```
#!/bin/bash

INFO=($(curl -sS -X POST http://node.moneroclub.com:8880/json_rpc -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"\
get_info"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' | jq '.result.height'))

echo $INFO
```

Alternatively, using moneroblocks.info:

```
#!/bin/bash

INFO=($(curl -sS -X GET http://moneroblocks.info/api/get_stats/ | jq '.height|tonumber'))

echo $INFO
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Maybe, they're not "simpler", because depending on the platform, one needs to install extra software. Out-of-the-box, I don't have `jq` on macOS (but I didn't specify so in my question). However, both of your `curl` and `jq` methods are definitely faster than using `ruby`. I will adjust my question in that sense, so that I can accept your answer. One remark though: I had to remove the backslash in your first code example for it to work.

Answer (score 5):

Currently, I am using **ruby** to parse the JSON returned from [moneroblocks.info](http://moneroblocks.info/api/get_stats/):

```
ruby << END_OF_RUBY
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'
open ("http://moneroblocks.info/api/get_stats/") { |src|
      puts JSON.parse(src.read)["height"]
}
END_OF_RUBY
```

Which right nows returns: `1140328`

Answer (score 4):

If you have a daemon running on your own machine, use:

`height=$(monerod print_height)`

This will save the height as the shell variable $height.

I see now that the question was for using a block explorer. Oh well.